# I am trying to concatenate innerTextvalue as below but not working

Tags: html, node.js

i am trying to concatenate the value like below..but it is  not working..need help pls

```
<a href = "/confirmpage/C10607'+" document.getElementById('bookdate').innerText" class="btn btn-success " >Book</a>
```

expecting output like
/confirmpage/C1060715082020

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that you are using vanilla javascript, this is not how you would redirect users to some dynamically constructed url.

What I would suggest is to set the href property at page load.
Within the script section of your template,

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("idOfYourAnchorTag").href = "/confirmpage/C10607" + document.getElementById('bookdate').innerText; 
};
```

Comment: Thanks.. i have called a function onclick of button and achieved the result.